# How to pull from my Github webhook?

Tags: php, git, github

I am trying to get my webhook set up correctly. Right now I have a githook.php file that contains the following function:

```
function gitPull()
{
    $cmd ='cd /public_html/ethanzh; git pull -u origin master git@github.com:ethanzh/NumberGame_JS.git 2>&1;';

    $str = shell_exec($cmd);

    if(strpos($str, 'error') !== false)
        throw new Exception("Shell error: \n" . $str);

    return $str;
}
```

When I check my webhook from the Github website, I am shown this error:

```
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Now, I don't have any branches in my repo, everything is being pushed straight to the 'master' branch (I'm the only person working on it).

I think my problem has to do with the line that's actually pulling from the repo. What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `-u`. Though it's exposed, it's relatively internal to Git. It's not like `push -u`.

> **-u**
>   **--update-head-ok**
>
> By default git fetch refuses to update the head which corresponds to the current branch. This flag disables the check. This
>   is purely for the internal use for git pull to communicate with git
>   fetch, and unless you are implementing your own Porcelain you are not
>   supposed to use it.

Second, there's no reason to specify the repository URI in the last argument. You're in a Git repository, so `origin` is already defined (unless you named another remote). You should be just fine with this:

```
git pull origin master
```

See the [git pull docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) if you need more detail.